# Web API File Upload Problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, ninject.web.mvc

Using MVC 4 I'm trying to build a Web API controller where you can upload an image. After the upload is complete the controller should save the image in the database. Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadPhoto(int thirdPartyID)
{            
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new Exception(); // divided by zero

    byte[] data = null;
    var filename = string.Empty;

    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(y =>
    {
        foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
        {
            filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
            data = file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;                            
        }

        var image = this.GetImageFrom(data);            
        var member = this.GetMemberBy(thirdPartyID);

        member.ProfileImage = data; 

        this.memberService.Save();                        
    });           
}
```

The problem occurs when the following line executes:

```
this.memberService.Save();
```

I'm using Ninject and Entity Framework. When this executes I get the error: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. I'm assuming this is happening because the 'ContinueWith' is executing asynchronously within a different request scope than what my DI has bound the original DbContext? Here is my DI bindings for my UOW:

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InScope(x => HttpContext.Current);
```

I've read how to change the DI so its scope is bound to an object, but this is a large project and I'm not comfortable at this stage changing the composition root. Does anyone have a work-around that doesn't involve changing the DI? I tried changing the line

```
Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(y =>...
```

to run synchronously with

```
Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).RunSynchronously();
```

or

```
Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).Wait();
```

The 'RunSynchronously' method gives me an error, the Wait() method just hangs. I just need to upload an image then store it in the database.

EDIT
Just came acorss this: [Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201255/request-content-readasmultipartasync-never-returns). I updated my code based on that post and it fixed my problem!

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723064/webapi-formdata-upload-to-db-with-extra-parameters

Comment: Please look at these 3 links. I hope they should solve your problem: 1.Henrik's Blog: [`Asynchronous File Upload using ASP.NET Web API`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx) 2.Sample code : [`ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-File-Upload-a8c0fb0d) 3.Nice tutorial: [`A guide to asynchronous file uploads in ASP.NET Web API RTM`](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/)