# How to send zip files to ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, zip

I'm wondering how I can send a zip file to a WebApi controller and vice versa.
The problem is that my WebApi uses json to transmit data. A zip file is not serializable, either is a stream. A string would be serializable. But there has to be an other solution than to convert the zip into a string and than send the string. That just sounds wrong.

Any idea how this is done?

Comment: If you need to consume binary, why would you restrict yourself to only allowing JSON?  WebApi supports several means of reading binary, either via multipart or a raw byte stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your API method expects an `HttpRequestMessage` then you can pull the stream from that:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var stream = GetStreamFromUploadedFile(request);

    // do something with the stream, then return something
}

private static Stream GetStreamFromUploadedFile(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    // Awaiting these tasks in the usual manner was deadlocking the thread for some reason.
    // So for now we're invoking a Task and explicitly creating a new thread.
    // See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15201255/328193
    IEnumerable<HttpContent> parts = null;
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => parts = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result.Contents,
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                        TaskScheduler.Default)
        .Wait();

    Stream stream = null;
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => stream = parts.First().ReadAsStreamAsync().Result,
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                        TaskScheduler.Default)
        .Wait();
    return stream;
}
```

This works for me when posting an HTTP form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a simple HttpResponseMessage, with a StreamContent inside to GET, download file

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var path = @"C:\Temp\file.zip";
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                            {
                                FileName = "file.zip"
                            };
    return result;
}
```

and for POST, upload file

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
    if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }


    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("C:\Temp");

    var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
        ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>
        {

            string file1 = provider.BodyPartFileNames.First().Value;
            // this is the file name on the server where the file was saved 

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.")
            };
        }
    );
    return task;
}
```