# How To Download Zip folder using web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating two projects:

1. Mvc
2. web api

I am make request from mvc controller action method to web api controller action method.on web api method I'm create zip folder but
**I don't know how to download this zip folder**.

Comment: You sure "zip" doesn't mean zip **file**? If not, then what is a "zip folder"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Zip file as Response in Web Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992973/return-zip-file-as-response-in-web-api)

Comment: There is no such thing as a zip folder. zips are files, that may contain multiple files in folders. The question is *very* hard to understand. Are you asking how to send a binary file as a response? [This is answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api), essentially you return a `StreamContent`

Comment: @Liam not a good duplicate, the answer isn't clear and even uses XElement for some reason

Comment: Both questions are pretty poor IMO

Comment: Could also refer to [How do I ZIP a file in C#, using no 3rd-party APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen:Zip Folder means Compressed folder.

Comment: But if it is a file, then this is simply about downloading a file from a website, or serving up a file from your website, the "zip" part is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen:but inside zip folder there is large number of images available.

Comment: But this does not matter. Downloading a "zip file" is still just about "downloading a file", what is *inside* the file does not matter. Unless you mean that "download" means something other than downloading the file. Please simply explain in detail what the problem is.